# JSOUP - Element Not Removing from Elements

Tags: java, android-studio, android-asynctask, jsoup

I'm scrapping data from a website and removing some HTML elements that aren't needed.

```
Elements results = docu.select("tr");
        results.select("td > strong").remove();
        results.select("td > b").remove();
        results.select("td > p > strong").remove();
        results.select("td.showingInfo").remove();
```

Since these are all children elements, their upper parent element (td) still exists within Results. I try removing it via using a for each loop method:

```
Elements resultsData = results.select("tr > td");
int i = 0;

Log.d("Course Data Size", String.valueOf(resultsData.size()));

for (Element e:results) {

 if (!e.hasText() && e.isBlock()) {

 e.remove();

}
  Log.d("Text", String.valueOf(e));

  Log.d("Index", String.valueOf(i++));
}

Log.d("Course Data Size", String.valueOf(resultsData.size()));
```

But these Elements still exist, despite being found and editable within that same if condition. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Logs:(NOTE: the opening element tag for "td" was changed to td so it can be shown on stackoverflow)

> 05-07  14:53:01.089 32524-32550 D/Results Data Size: 51
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.092 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.092 32524-32550 D/Index: 0
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.093 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">Introduction to Human Computer Interaction
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.093 32524-32550 D/Index: 1
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.093 32524-32550 D/Element: td width="88" align="left" valign="top">
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.094 32524-32550 D/Index: 2
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.094 32524-32550 D/Element: td width="496" align="left" valign="top">4.000
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.094 32524-32550 D/Index: 3
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.094 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.095 32524-32550 D/Index: 4
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.095 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">Seidenberg School of CSIS
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.097 32524-32550 D/Index: 5
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.099 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.099 32524-32550 D/Index: 6
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.100 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top"> Computer Science
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.100 32524-32550 D/Index: 7
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.101 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.101 32524-32550 D/Index: 8
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.101 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top"> Undergraduate
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.101 32524-32550 D/Index: 9
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.102 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.102 32524-32550 D/Index: 10
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.102 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top"> none
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.102 32524-32550 D/Index: 11
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.102 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.102 32524-32550 D/Index: 12
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.103 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top"> CS 242 Minimum Grade of C
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.103 32524-32550 D/Index: 13
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.104 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.104 32524-32550 D/Index: 14
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.107 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">
>
> : Design principles and practical techniques will be introduced for building and evaluating user-centered, intuitive, effective computing systems. Topics include principles of usage design, interface elements, user psychology, prototyping, and an introduction to interface evaluation. Project examples may include web design multimedia interfaces, mobile and specialize applications.
>
> : PLV: Spring
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.107 32524-32550 D/Index: 15
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.107 32524-32550 D/Element: td width="126" align="left" valign="top">
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.107 32524-32550 D/Index: 16
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.107 32524-32550 D/Element: td width="464" align="left" valign="top">72805
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.107 32524-32550 D/Index: 17
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.107 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.107 32524-32550 D/Index: 18
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.107 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">CS
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.107 32524-32550 D/Index: 19
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.107 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.108 32524-32550 D/Index: 20
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.108 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">359
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.108 32524-32550 D/Index: 21
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.108 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.108 32524-32550 D/Index: 22
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.108 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">Introduction to Human Computer Interaction
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.108 32524-32550 D/Index: 23
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.108 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.108 32524-32550 D/Index: 24
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.108 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">New York City
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.108 32524-32550 D/Index: 25
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.108 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.108 32524-32550 D/Index: 26
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.108 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">Lecture
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.108 32524-32550 D/Index: 27
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.109 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.109 32524-32550 D/Index: 28
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.109 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top"> To Be Determined
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.109 32524-32550 D/Index: 29
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.109 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.109 32524-32550 D/Index: 30
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.109 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">Plus additional hours online. This is a web assisted course that requires attendance on campus and regular online participation. 
>  Meets with CS 659.
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.109 32524-32550 D/Index: 31
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.109 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.109 32524-32550 D/Index: 32
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.109 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top"> None
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.109 32524-32550 D/Index: 33
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.110 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.110 32524-32550 D/Index: 34
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.110 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">0
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.110 32524-32550 D/Index: 35
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.111 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.111 32524-32550 D/Index: 36
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.111 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">10
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.111 32524-32550 D/Index: 37
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.111 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.111 32524-32550 D/Index: 38
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.111 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">2
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.111 32524-32550 D/Index: 39
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.111 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.111 32524-32550 D/Index: 40
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.111 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top"> TBA
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.111 32524-32550 D/Index: 41
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.111 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top">
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.111 32524-32550 D/Index: 42
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.112 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top" colspan="2">
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.112 32524-32550 D/Index: 43
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.112 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top" colspan="2">
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.112 32524-32550 D/Index: 44
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.112 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top" colspan="2">
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.112 32524-32550 D/Index: 45
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.113 32524-32550 D/Element: td align="left" valign="top" colspan="2">
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.113 32524-32550 D/Index: 46
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.113 32524-32550 D/Element: td> 06:10 pm - 09:00 pm
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.113 32524-32550 D/Index: 47
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.114 32524-32550 D/Element: td>R
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.114 32524-32550 D/Index: 48
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.114 32524-32550 D/Element: td> To Be Determined
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.114 32524-32550 D/Index: 49
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.115 32524-32550 D/Element: td>09/05/2018 - 12/21/2018
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.115 32524-32550 D/Index: 50
>
> 05-07  14:53:01.115 32524-32550 D/Results Data Size: 51

Comment: have you output the doc content after removing?

Comment: @lucumt Yes, I have a Log after the if condition to print out the object & index, as well as a Log after the for each loop that tells me the size. The size directly before and after are the same. Ill edit the log's and code output on the post

Comment: you need to use doc.asXML() to check if it was removed

Comment: @lucumt I'm not seeing that as a method under Doc. I tried using an XML parser and no luck.